# Windows Media Classic can't open a zipped video

Tags: windows-7, video

I tried to open a zipped video with Windows Media Classic and an error appears saying:

```
''WM ASF Reader::Raw Video 2

Media Type 0:
--------------------------
Video: G2M3 1440x870 29.97fps 58kbps

AM_MEDIA_TYPE: 
majortype: MEDIATYPE_Video {73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
subtype: Unknown GUID Name {334D3247-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
formattype: FORMAT_VideoInfo {05589F80-C356-11CE-BF01-00AA0055595A}
bFixedSizeSamples: 0
bTemporalCompression: 1
lSampleSize: 0
cbFormat: 88

VIDEOINFOHEADER:
rcSource: (0,0)-(1440,870)
rcTarget: (0,0)-(1440,870)
dwBitRate: 58306
dwBitErrorRate: 0
AvgTimePerFrame: 333667

BITMAPINFOHEADER:
biSize: 40
biWidth: 1440
biHeight: 870
biPlanes: 1
biBitCount: 24
biCompression: G2M3
biSizeImage: 80598
biXPelsPerMeter: 0
biYPelsPerMeter: 0
biClrUsed: 0
biClrImportant: 0

pbFormat:
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 05 00 00 66 03 00 00 ........ ...f...
0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 05 00 00 66 03 00 00 ........ ...f...
0020: c2 e3 00 00 00 00 00 00 63 17 05 00 00 00 00 00 Âã......c.......
0030: 28 00 00 00 a0 05 00 00 66 03 00 00 01 00 18 00 (... ...f.......
0040: 47 32 4d 33 d6 3a 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 G2M3Ö:..........
0050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         ........          ''
```

Does anybody know what I have to do in order to see the video? I can only hear the voice…

Comment: I may not understand. Why don't you unzip it first?

Comment: Do you mean Media Player Classic?

Answer (score 1):

That's a GoToMeeting WMV file.

You either need to [download the GoToMeeting codec](http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/GoToMeeting/help_files/GTM080011) or convert it to regular WMV using `g2mtranscoder.exe` which can be [found at Citrix' site](http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/meeting/knowledge_articles/000081292?title=Using%20The%20GoToMeeting%20Transcoding%20Wizard%7D).